# Trying to generate an array of hashes in Node from model object

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, hash, sendgrid-api-v3

In order to send an email to multiple recipients via SendGrid API v3 using a dynamic template, I need to pass an email parameter like:

```
 "to":[
        {
           "email":"example1@example.com"
        },
        { "email": "example2@example.com"
        }
     ],
```

Obviously I am not wanting to hard code these email addresses s.t. they are dynamic.

I currently generate a list of emails with this code:

```
  // loop through users
  var users = group.user;
  var emails = users.map(function (obj) {
    return obj.email;
  });
```

Which returns eg:

[ 'example1@example.com',
  'example2@example.com' ]

How do I return instead the array of hashes:

```
[
        {
           "email":"example1@example.com"
        },
        { "email": "example2@example.com"
        }
     ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe what you are trying to say is hashmap, not hashes, if not, I don't understand the question.

To achieve the lists of maps that you mention, your code should be something like:

```
// loop through users
  var users = group.user;
  var emails = users.map(function (obj) {
    return {email: obj.email};
  });
```

Every item of the list would have email as key, and the email as value.

What is a hash: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function

What is a hash table: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table

What is a js object: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp

Comment: this is helpful, but does not quite get me there.  this function returns for users -- [ { email: 'example1@example.com' },
  { email: 'example2@example.com' }]. Instead, I need the key to be in quotes, eg [ { "email": example2@example.com..]

Comment: var emailsString = JSON.stringify(emails); works to convert the key to a string

Comment: The quotes are part of the model in JSON, the object doesn't need those quotes.

When sending that object over HTTP, your library will probably convert it to JSON without the need for the JSON.stringify. Anyway, it's important to notice that it is not converting the key to a string. The key is already a string, it's just that printing it in js doesn't show the quotes.